# Определить последнюю цифру числа в числовом поле

Tags: access, vb6

`Access 2007`. В отчете выходит разное количество часов. Как определить последнюю цифру числа в числовом поле (диапазон чисел - от нуля до 3000),  по последней цифре ( 0, 5,6,7,8,9 -часов, 1 - час, 2,3,4 часа) менять слово в текстовом поле часы, часов, час. Цифры - в числовом поле. Часы - в текстовом поле. Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Найти остаток от деления на 10 - по модулю 10 то биш. Поле MOD 10

Comment: Спасибо вопрос решен